# xmlHttp.send() doesn't seem to send

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to put together a basic Ajax sample for myself so I can later implement it in a game. The problem I am running into is the inability to send data to a .php file using the xmlHttp.send() method. My code is as follows:

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='level' value='0'>
```

JavaScript

```
function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send("level=" + document.getElementById('level').value);
}
```

PHP

```
$level = $_GET["level"];
echo "Result is: " . $level;
```

What am I doing wrong? I really cannot see any issues, I have tried changing "GET" to "POST" or writing "ajax.php?level=90" instead of just "ajax.php". Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending GET request with AJAX: the parameter should be attached with the URL:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?level=" + document.getElementById('level').value, true); 
xmlHttp.send();
```

While for sending PSOT, you can use:

```
 xmlHttp.open("POST", "ajax.php", true); 
 xmlHttp.send("level=" + document.getElementById('level').value);
```

Comment: I didn't think your solution was working for nearly two hours until I realized my web browsers were just keeping the old JavaScript in their caches. Thanks for your help.